# How am I able to dependency inject? PHP

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I'm trying to learn dependency injection to make things a lot easier, however I'm puzzled and not sure where to go from where I am right now.

Basically I have 3 classes: the core, an engine and an account class.

The account classes needs to be able to access engine methods, and the engine class needs to be able to access core methods. Also the core must be able to access another class "settings".

I have an index file which includes all of the classes along with the settings and initiates them, I use a __get to access my settings class as the variables are private. However I am getting errors such as "Argument 1 passed to Core::__construct() must be an instance of settings, none given,".

Here's what I have:

```
class core {
    protected $test;

    public function __construct(Settings $test){
        $this->test = $test;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is *Type Hinting*, and nothing to do with `Dependency Injection`.

You have specified that the parameter to the `__contruct()` function must be of type `Settings`. Obviously whatever you are passing as the `$test` parameter is not a Settings object.

So you should be calling like this

```
$xxx = new Settings();
$yyy = new core($xxx);
```

Now the parameter to the `core` contructor method is of type `Settings`

You say your index.php looks like this :-

```
$settings = new settings(); 
$core = new core($settings);
```

In that case your settings class is called `Class settings` and your prototype should also have a lower case `s` like

```
class core {
    protected $test;

    public function __construct(settings $test){
        $this->test = $test;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by the third sentence, "Settings" is the other class that I am trying to inject into the current class "Core" and "$test" is the variable I am using. $xxx = new Settings();
$yyy = new core($xxx); I have also tried this

Comment: No I already have that but I'm not sure where to go from there, my index is like that:   $settings = new settings();
  $core = new core($settings);

Comment: What version of PHP are you using

Comment: 5.6.0, how am I able to call the __get method from the Settings class so the core can access them?

Comment: See additional part of my answer

Comment: Would something along the lines of this work? I tried it but got no results when I tried printing it?  class Core {

  protected $data;

   public function __construct(Settings $data){
    $this->data = $data->__get('data');
   }

Comment: Never mind I think it is working now, the page was just cached.